# A way to load service to all of the components in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, angularjs-rootscope

I built a service that called `lang.service.ts`. What it does is simply a `key: value` mechanism. Whenever I need it to my component, I import it and declare it in the `constructor` and then I use it as `{{lang('key').text}}`. so far, so good.

The thing is that I've noticed that I'm gonna load it for each component, like for `view-header.component.ts`, `view-footer.components.ts` and a lot of other components. I never used Angular 1, but IIRC, I could do there something like `rootScope.lang(..)` and it could've accomplish what I was looking for. Is there a way to do something like that in Angular 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you register your service at your root componet, all child components will have access to the service.

On your root component...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { YourService } from './my-servive.service.ts';
import { ChildComponent } from './child-component.component.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'root-component',
  providers: [YourService],
  directives: [ChildComponent],
  template: `<child-component></child-component>`
})
export class RootComponent {}
```

On your child component...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { YourService } from './my-servive.service.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  contructor(private myService: YourService) {}
}
```

Hope this help you.